# How can I generate a valid (but unaccessible) custom bitcoin address?

Tags: sha, bitcoin

I want to generate a bitcoin address with a long prefix (like https://blockchain.info/address/1CounterpartyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXUWLpVr) but am unsure how to do so.

I understand I won't be able to access any bitcoins.

I understand there is some SHA-256 hashing involved. If you are able to help please provide some example code.

Thanks!

Edit: These need to be valid bitcoin addresses with a custom long prefix.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby, you can make some fake ones. https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakerbitcoin `Faker::Bitcoin.address`

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as I want the address to have a custom prefix.

Comment: Maybe you could just make your own version of https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker/bitcoin.rb ?